# Metric space, identify E' (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is:

Consider   $ \mathbb{R^2} $ with the usual metric and let

$E = \{ (t, \sin t) : t > 0 \} $ . Identify $E'$ explicitly.

Thank you so much !

Comment: What does $E'$ denote?

Comment: complement of E

Comment: Okay. Well, the set $E$ is just the graph of the sine function for $t>0$, so the complement of $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is everything not on this graph

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder is it just a graph of F(t) = sine t?

Comment: Yes, $E$ is the graph of $F(t)$ for $t>0$.

Comment: Can I say complement of cosine is cosine t? or just shaded everything other than the line cosine t in graph?

Comment: I don't know what "the complement of cosine is cosine t" means, so I'm not sure what you're asking. The complement of a set $A$ is everything outside of $A$ (but still in the universe you care about; for your problem the universe is $\mathbb{R}^2$). The set $E$ in the problem you posted above is a portion of the graph of the sine function; the complement of $E$ is the set of points that do not lie on this portion of the graph (that is, these are the points outside of $E$).

Comment: To get curly braces in $\LaTeX$, use `\{` and `\}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R'$ contains all points $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ that are not of the form $(t,\sin t)$ for some $t>0$. That is
$$ E'=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x\le 0\lor y\ne\sin x\}.$$